# Объясните код c#

Tags: c#

Вот код. Что делает, понять не могу. Да, методы делают сериализацию и обратно, но, например, что делает строка `List<ListNode> arr = new List<ListNode>();`?

```
public void Serialize(FileStream s)
{
    List<ListNode> arr = new List<ListNode>();
    ListNode temp = new ListNode();
    temp = Head;

    //transform nodes into List
    do
    {
        arr.Add(temp);
        temp = temp.Next;
    } while (temp != null);

    //write into file; data is modify for store index of .Random node
    using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(s))
        foreach (ListNode n in arr)
            w.WriteLine(n.Data.ToString() + ":" + arr.IndexOf(n.Rand).ToString());
}

public void Deserialize(FileStream s)
{
    List<ListNode> arr = new List<ListNode>();
    ListNode temp = new ListNode();
    Count = 0;
    Head = temp;
    string line;

    //try read file and create List of nodes
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
        {
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!line.Equals(""))
                {
                    Count++;
                    temp.Data = line;
                    ListNode next = new ListNode();
                    temp.Next = next;
                    arr.Add(temp);
                    next.Prev = temp;
                    temp = next;
                }
            }
        }

        //declare Tail
        Tail = temp.Prev;
        Tail.Next = null;

        //return refs to Random nodes and restore Data
        foreach (ListNode n in arr)
        {
            n.Rand = arr[Convert.ToInt32(n.Data.Split(':')[1])];
            n.Data = n.Data.Split(':')[0];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Что вы в указанной строке считаете кавычками, угловые скобки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этих кавычках пишется обобщенный тип. В подсказках тебе будет показывать только список такого типа **`List<T>`** тут `T` это тот самый *обобщенный тип* который позволяет работать с любим типом данных только нужно наперед указать его в объявлении класса. Для чего это?
Вот в пример тебе обобщенный метод не класс на методе будет нагляднее но суть от этого почти не измениться:

```
void Swap<T>(ref T a,ref T b){
    T temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

Всем известный метод смена переменных значениями. Но что тут делает какой-то тип `T` в треугольных кавычках? Это что-то на подобие `object` но во время вызова метода пользователь должен указать в этих кавычках какой тип данных принимает метод в качестве аргумента. Да, конечно, вы могли перегрузить метод для всех типов которые вы будете использовать? Но зачем (если вы не индус кончено), если можно сделать такой элегантный и простой код. В библиотеке классов [`System.Collections.Generics`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) собраны несколько классов для работы с обобщенными типами, такие как: `List<T>`, `Dictionary<K,V>`, `Queue<T>`, `Stack<T>` и так далее. Вы наверное успели заметить какие-то другие буквы помимо `Т` в `Dictionary<K,V>`. Да в этом почти никакого отличия и нету. Вы можете как захотите назвать этот тип. Но принято если тип 1 то называть его `T`, а если 2 то `T,U`.

---

Теперь о коде. Если конкретно о коде который Вы попросили объяснить в комментариях:

```
List<ListNode> arr = new List<ListNode>(); //Список экземпляров класса ListNode (динамический массив)
ListNode temp = new ListNode(); //Новый экземпляр класса ListNode
temp = Head;//Присваивание экземпляру класса ListNode значение Head

//В цикле мы все узлы из файла переносим в список для дальнейшей работы с ним.
do
{
    arr.Add(temp);//Тут мы добавляем в список узел
    temp = temp.Next;//Тут мы переходим к следующему
} while (temp != null);//Пока узлы существуют
```

---

Думаю мой небольшой рассказ помог Вам понять предназначение обобщенных типов. Подробнее о них можете почитать по данной [ссылке](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

**SeeSharp**

Comment: Спасибо,очень помогли,а с кодом можете помочь разобраться,поверхностно я понимаю,это сериализация и десериализация,читаем и записываем,а больше ничего и не понятно)

Comment: @Андрей обновил ответ